# Can't create directory with mkdirs() - android

Tags: android, file, mkdir, mkdirs

I try to create a directory and use the following code:

```
boolean success = true;
String rootDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
folder = new File(rootDirectory, "Directory");
if(!(folder.exists())) {
     success = folder.mkdirs();
} else {

}

if(success) {
   Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "DIR created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
} else {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "DIR not created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I also searched for the folder if it was created, there is none.

Permissions are granted:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I also tried to ask for permission during runtime, it seems like the app has got the permission, therefore it cannot be the problem.

Some months ago I created another application and used identical code and the identical Sdk version, still it does not work with this one. I get "DIR not created successfully" and I do not know why, please help me figure out why I cannot create the directory.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129852/discussion-on-question-by-progfroz-cant-create-directory-with-mkdirs-androi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code below

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + java.io.File.separator +"Directory");
if (!directory.exists())
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
          (directory.mkdirs() ? "Directory has been created" : "Directory not created"),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
else
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Directory exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

For Android **API 23** (Marshmallow) and greater, we have to allow [dangerous permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous) otherwise our code will not work as we expected.

Comment: I used your exact code but it still does not work.. I get the toast of "Dir not created"

Comment: Is there maybe something in the gradle files what can interrupt the creation of a directory?

Comment: Do you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission? I am not talking about permission declaration in your manifest file. I am saying do you have permission to write?

Comment: I tried with runtime:
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

Comment: Just go to your app settings and allow write sd card permission and rerun your application

Comment: Oh man thank you very much, finally it created a directory. Was too simple to mind about I guess.

Comment: For latest android versions we have to allow dangerous permission otherwise our code will not work as we expected

Answer (score 5):

Asking for `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is no more sufficient for Android 10+. Now you have also enable access to legacy external storage in manifest:

```
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

In the new Android update `API 30` you can only write in your app local files `app-specific files`

```
File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "YOUR_DIR");
dir.mkdirs();
```

or in the external storage of your app `Android/data`

```
final File dir = new File(myContext.getExternalFilesDir("FolderName"),"YOUR_DIR");
```

UPDATE

this answer provided another solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/65744517/8195076

UPDATE

another way is to grant this permission in `manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968986/8195076

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" +"MyDir";
File dir = new File(path);
if(!dir.exists())
{
    dir.mkdirs()
}
```

Comment: This code does not seem to work, it cannot resolve "exist".

Comment: i am sorry its file.exists()