# SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException Cannot open database : is not readable

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room, android-11

I am using Room DB to save data locally in android.

Now, I want to preserve the data even user uninstall the application or do clear storage.

So, I created Room DB in following location.

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getPath()
```

Everything works fine.

But if I clear the storage or uninstall the application and I open the application again, I am getting following error.

> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/storage/emulated/0/Download/database/hhcf': File /storage/emulated/0/Download/database/hhcf is not readable

This issue coming in Android 11. For Android 9 no excetion is there.

I have granted following permissions as well.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And,

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

in application tag.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to request user permission to get this permission, adding it only in manifest won't work, at least it didn't for me. I did something like this:

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
public void checkFileAccessPermission() {
    if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
        return;
    }
    Intent getPermission = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(getPermission, 123);
}
```

It's a solution from this thread: [How to obtain MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250814/how-to-obtain-manage-external-storage-permission)

But remember that if you want your app to be on the google play store you need to justify to google why you need this permission like this article says: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955?hl=en

If you use another path for files e.g method getFilesDir() you won't have this problem either, but it's only good if developing a new app, or something like that.